# How to Stop the content from scrolling under Fixed header?

Tags: php, html, css, stylesheet

There is a wrapper.
then there is header 10%;
then 
section: 
min-height:80%;
height auto;

[screenshot ---> This is overlapping going under header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zuPy.png)
when i scroll, the content goes under the header. 
I want things to stop there...
[Screenshot---> This is normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh4DZ.png)

```
#wrapper{
position:absolute;
padding-top:50px;
height:100%;
width:100%;
top:150px;
left:0;
margin:0;
border:2px soild green;/**/
}


header {
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
    background-color:#2e72ce;
float:top;
color:black;        
text-align:center;
margin:0;
opacity:0.4;
padding:0px;
overflow-x:hidden;
width:100%;
height:calc(10% - 9px);
 z-index:9999;   
 clear:both;
```

}

```
#main_section {

position:relative;
top:-50px;         /*-5px proper location */
float:left;
padding-top:0;
padding-left:60px;
width:95%;
bottom:0;
right:0;
min-height:80%;
height:auto;
border:2px solid red;/**/
```

}

```
<html><!----HTML FIle---->
 <body >
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <img src="img/ztlogo.png" height="50px"/>
         </header>
              <section id="main_section">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of your opacity in that header color - hence what's behind it, you can see through.

A simple fix could be to add another white div behind the blue opaque color. But, you want to make it to where you can't see through the header.

Comment: No, I made it **transparent** so that i can explain it here...
but i want the **red border** line to stop at **black menu bar** and _not go under_ it ....

Comment: Then fix the element with the red box so it doesn't scroll under your fixed header.